# Was looking at an example that uses Gauss' Theorem. How is this the normal vector?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I was reading my calculus textbook by Stewart to find examples on solving the left hand side of Gauss' Theorem and the only example I came across was example where I didn't understand a step in the solution to it sadly.

We have the electric field equation: $$\textbf{E}(\textbf{x}) = \frac{\epsilon Q}{|\textbf{x}|^3}\textbf{x}$$ where $\textbf{x} = <x,y,z>$ is a *positional vector*. We use the LHS of the Divergence Theorem equation to get the divergence: $$\int_{S_2} = \textbf{E} \cdot d\textbf{S} = 4\pi \epsilon Q$$.

I know that this works out to be $\int_{S_2} \textbf{E} \cdot d\textbf{S} = \int_{S_2} \textbf{E} \cdot \textbf{n} dS$ and we need to find the normal vector. The book claims that the normal vector is $\textbf{n} = \frac{\textbf{x}}{|\textbf{x}|}$. I don't understand how it arrived to this conclusion; I thought the unit normal vector equation was $\textbf{n} = \frac{\textbf{T}'(t)}{|\textbf{T}'(t)|}$ (where $\textbf{T}(t)$ is the *unit tangent vector*), right? This would imply that the *positional vector* is also the derivative of the unit tangent vector, right? Can someone please explain/show how $\frac{\textbf{x}}{|\textbf{x}|}$ the normal vector?

Comment: Wrong and wrong. Draw a circle in two dimensions. The normal vector is by definition perpendicular to the tangent.

Comment: @KurtG. I apologize for the late reply. I had a lot going on over the last 3 days. I understand that the normal vector is by definition perpendicular to to the tangent. It's just that I thought the position vector $\textbf{x}$ is tangential to the surface. That's why it wouldn't make sense to me that it's unit vector $\frac{\textbf{V}}{|\textbf{V}|}$ is defined as the normal vector. It's why I typed out the equation for the normal vector $\textbf{n}$ to draw attention to that. Do you understand my point of confusion now?

Comment: For the life of me: I cannot follow this reasoning, and why should I? Draw pictures in the future and you will hopefully see what those vectors are.

Comment: @KurtG. I had to reread the problem and it says that the electric charge, Q, is located at the origin (which the positional vector points from the origin). So in 2-D the electric field vector, E, should point outward from the center and tangential to the circumference of the 2-D circle representing a slice of the 3-D electric field. So $\textbf{x}$ would indeed be parallel to the normal vector and thus the unit vector of the positional vector $\frac{\textbf{x}}{|\textbf{x}|}$ would in fact satisfy the equation $\int_{S_2} \textbf{F} \cdot \textbf{n} dS$. Can I presume this to be correct?

Comment: @KurtG. I was confused because I thought the origin was some particle along the boundary of the electric field and that the particle was circulating around the field like it would in Stokes' Theorem. I was thinking from the framing of Stokes' Theorem and somehow confused the concepts between it and Gauss' Theorem and I had circulation about the boundary on my mind. I apologize for the confusion!

Comment: All you should have been done is what I mentioned multiple times: [picture](https://images.app.goo.gl/aGz7aBn7h96QSYVR6).